# Verificar variavel vazia no PHP

Tags: php

Quanto vou verificar uma variável vazia no PHP estou usando a negação da função **empty()**, funciona, mas não seu se isso esta correto e gostaria de saber se ha outras maneiras de fazer isso?

```
if (!empty($numer)) {    
   echo "<h2>O numero informado foi  " . $numer . "</h2>";    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Se sua variável deve ser um número, não utilize `empty`. Basta ler o que a documentação diz:

> ## Valor Retornado
>
> Retorna `FALSE` se var existir e não estiver vazia e
>   não conter um valor zerado. Caso contrário retornará `TRUE`.
>
> O que é visto abaixo é considerado vazio:
>
> - "" (uma string vazia)
> - 0 (0 como um inteiro)
> - 0.0 (0 como um ponto flutuante)
> - "0" (0 como uma string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (um array vazio)
> - $var; (uma variável declarada, mas sem valor)

Ou seja, se a variável for igual a 0, `empty` irá retornar verdadeiro, mesmo sendo um número válido.

Se, de alguma forma, a variável pode chegar em estar definida, utilize o `isset` para verificar sua existência e `is_numeric` para verificar se é numérica:

```
isset($number) and is_numeric($number)
```

Mas a única situação que imagino, no momento, que seja plausível verificar a existência da variável é quando a mesma vem por uma requisição HTTP e neste caso o ideal é fazer:

```
$number = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'number', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Assim, `$number` sempre estará definida e será igual ao valor, se o valor informado foi um número, falso se o filtro falhar ou nulo se a variável não estava definida em `$_GET`.

Answer (score 2):

Não tem problema nenhum utilizar `empty()`, mas `if(!$numer)` também funciona.
O bom do `empty()` é que ele valida se a variável em questão é nula, vazia **ou** false, o que é bom dependendo do seu caso.

Answer (score 1):

[Essa pagina](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/types.comparisons.php) mostra a comparação entre as funções empty(),is_null(),isset()... Você pode verificar a que melhor se aplica ao seu caso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer desta maneira:

```
<?php
$numer = $_GET['num'];
if(!is_numeric($numer) or !$numer or $numer == 0){

      echo "<h2>Nenhum número foi informado</h2>";
    }else{
    echo "<h2>O numero informado foi  " . $numer . "</h2>";
    }
```

Desta forma se o valor de $numer não for numérico, estiver vazio ou estiver com valor de 0, irá informar que nenhum número foi informado. Caso ao contrario, ele apresentará o valor da variável.

Comment: E se `$numer` (*sic*) for igual a 0?

Comment: Verdade amigo. Não tinha pensado nessa hipótese, irei adicionar uma nova condição na resposta.